# Solving feature bias issues in Learning to Rank with implicit feedback

Tags: machine-learning, classification, computational-statistics, ranking

I have a learning to rank system where implicit feedback (from user clicks) is used to determine +ve and -ve examples for the training. The problem is that (obviously) the learner sees only the top few ranked results (+ve or more relevant examples will appear at the beginning). This introduces some kind of a bias in the learning problem.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's problematic that you're not getting full support.

One way to solve this is to produce:

1. A model to decide whether or not results are shown - $P(shown)$, and then
2. Another model, $P(relevant|shown)$.

Then $P(relevant)=P(relevant|shown)P(shown)$.

Of course, as your model drifts over time, it can be tough to maintain.  But you might be able to maintain a time-based $P(shown|time)$ model, where each time you update your model you keep the old model and maintain a link to the training data used to generate it.